# Compile error with UrbanAirpush about some files missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, urbanairship.com

I got this error when compiling my code:

```
Ld /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BusinessIdea-degqppvjmvixescuvttxsvcksqtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BusinessIdea.app/BusinessIdea normal i386
    cd /Users/owner12/Desktop/BusinessIdea
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BusinessIdea-degqppvjmvixescuvttxsvcksqtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/owner12/Desktop/BusinessIdea/BusinessIdea/Airship -F/Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BusinessIdea-degqppvjmvixescuvttxsvcksqtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BusinessIdea-degqppvjmvixescuvttxsvcksqtf/Build/Intermediates/BusinessIdea.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BusinessIdea.build/Objects-normal/i386/BusinessIdea.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lUAirship-1.4.0 -lUAirshipFull-1.4.0 -o /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BusinessIdea-degqppvjmvixescuvttxsvcksqtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BusinessIdea.app/BusinessIdea

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[UAPushNotificationHandler playNotificationSound:] in UAPushNotificationHandler.o
      -[UAPushSettingsSoundsViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in UAPushSettingsSoundsViewController.o
  "_AudioServicesPlayAlertSound", referenced from:
      -[UAPushNotificationHandler playNotificationSound:] in UAPushNotificationHandler.o
      -[UAPushSettingsSoundsViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in UAPushSettingsSoundsViewController.o
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[UAPushNotificationHandler playNotificationSound:] in UAPushNotificationHandler.o
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationCopyMethod", referenced from:
      -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in libUAirship-1.4.0.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
      -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in libUAirship-1.4.0.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationCopyRealm", referenced from:
      -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in libUAirship-1.4.0.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
      -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in libUAirship-1.4.0.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationCreateFromResponse", referenced from:
      -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in libUAirship-1.4.0.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
      -[UA_ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in libUAirship-1.4.0.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
```

They are very cryptic and googling the whole error does not bring up much. Would anyone know why this happens and how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the following frameworks to your project. AudioServices, CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices, zlib, and libxml2. For libxml2 and zlib, you have to add 2 entries to `Header Search Paths` in your build settings. `/usr/include/` and `/usr/include/libxml2/`.

To add them (they are already included in Xcode), do this
[image]

Click the plus button, and add all the frameworks I listed above. (Cocoa.framework is not required, that's just from my project). This is located in your projects summary if you scroll down.

Comment: thanks! I am a little bit confused as to why I have to add those. I am working from another example where that app does not have these libraries....I am a bit confused.

Comment: They're needed by UrbanAirpush because they contain the methods for things like `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`, which are needed for  the project to compile. Your other projects might not have these as they don't use methods from these frameworks.

Comment: Would you know where should I download these frameworks from? I would figure it should have come with the UrbanAirship libraries, no?

Comment: You don't have to download them as they are already in Xcode. Check my edit.

Comment: Hmmm, can't seem to locate it. Is it under targets--> build phases? Or somewhere else?

Comment: It's under targets->summary, and you might have to scroll down. It's also in build phases, under `link binary with libraries`

Comment: Ah found that spot. But when I clicked the little + to add that Cocoa.framework, it wasn't listed in the options. What should be done to add it?

Comment: Cocoa.framework isn't needed for you (it's actually an OS X framework), it was just an example in the picture.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27055/discussion-between-genadinik-and-chris-loonam)